# datatable draw multiple rows using for loop

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have data table for user Reports, having columns `Report Id,Report Title,created date,created by`.
I have a list for Users who created these reports.
If i logged in as admin , only admin created list should display.
So I used for loop and code is like this.

```
var sub="@User.Identity.Name.Split('|')[0]";
sub = sub.toLowerCase();
var ListUser= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ListUser));
for ( i = 0; i < ListUser.length; i++) {
    if (ListUser[i].UserName.toLowerCase() == sub) {
        //// code to draw table
    }
}
```

I added `table.column(0).search(ListUser[i].ReportID).draw();`
But it will show only latest row. How to loop and draw table ?

Please help me here....

Comment: Please can anyone help me....

Comment: The variable with the name "sub" in your case is a String, maybe you expect an expression like @User.Identity.Name.Split('|')[0] without parantheses ?